# SQL Query works different than expected

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle10g

I have problems with understanding sql statement.
When I execute the it(see below), I'm getting only people with sgtn_typ 'L'.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT kun_id kid
                ,dep_id
                ,ddg_rang_g RANG
                ,dep_perf_g
                ,TO_CHAR(dep_buchwert + dep_kasse, '999G999G990D99') WERT
                ,kun_name1
                ,Kun_vorname
                ,kun_cust_id
                ,kun_strasse
                ,kun_plz
                ,kun_ort
                ,kun_e_mail
                ,kun_pseudonym
                ,kka_value
   FROM ddg, dep, kun, kat, kka, sgtn
  WHERE dep_spi_id = 245
        AND dep_abr_id = 24
        AND ddg_dgr_id = 3
        AND ddg_abr_id = dep_abr_id
        AND ddg_spi_id = dep_spi_id
        AND ddg_dep_id = dep_id
        AND dep_kun_id = kun_id
        AND kun_aktiv = 'J'
        AND dep_spi_id = kun_spi_id
        AND dep_id IS NOT NULL
        AND dep_id NOT IN (SELECT ddg_dep_id
                             FROM ddg
                            WHERE ddg_spi_id = 245
                                  AND ddg_abr_id = 0
                                  AND ddg_dgr_id = 1)
        AND kun_id = kka_kun_id
        AND kka_spi_id = 245
        AND kat_spi_id = 245
        AND kka_kat_kuerzel = kat_kuerzel
        AND kat_kuerzel = 'NSCH'
        AND kka_spi_id = sgtn_spi_id
        AND kka_kun_id = sgtn_kun_id
        AND sgtn_spi_id = 245
        AND sgtn_e_mail = kun_e_mail
        AND (sgtn_typ = 'L' 
           OR (sgtn_typ = 'T'
              AND sgtn_e_mail NOT IN (SELECT sgtn_e_mail
                                      FROM sgtn
                                      WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
                                      AND sgtn_typ = 'L'))
          )
  ORDER BY kun_id, sgtn_typ;
```

But when I execute this, I'm getting people with sgtn_typ 'T':

```
 SELECT *
   FROM sgtn
  WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
        AND (sgtn_typ = 'L' 
             OR (sgtn_typ = 'T'
                 AND sgtn_e_mail NOT IN (SELECT sgtn_e_mail
                                         FROM sgtn
                                         WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
                                         AND sgtn_typ = 'L'))
 )
  ORDER BY sgtn_kun_id;
```

I don't understand why? Could someone give me any clue? I was expecting, that I substitute all people with type 'L' and will get people with type 'T':

```
 AND (sgtn_typ = 'L'
         OR (sgtn_typ = 'T' 
              AND sgtn_e_mail NOT IN (SELECT sgtn_e_mail
                                     FROM sgtn
                                     WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
                                      AND sgtn_typ = 'L'))
       )
```

There are 'duplicates' in sgtn table(some people are entered with 'T' and 'L'). And apart from that the whole record is the same.

Table scheme are like the folowing:

SGTN:

```
SGTN_ID             NUMBER(22)
SGTN_SPI_ID             NUMBER(22)
SGTN_KUN_ID             NUMBER(22)
SGTN_TYP                VARCHAR2(4)
SGTN_GESCHLECHT     VARCHAR2(4)
SGTN_VORNAME        VARCHAR2(160)
SGTN_NAME1              VARCHAR2(240)
SGTN_STRASSE        VARCHAR2(240)
SGTN_PLZ                VARCHAR2(60)
SGTN_ORT                VARCHAR2(240)
SGTN_E_MAIL             VARCHAR2(240)
SGTN_GEB_DAT            DATE(7)
SGTN_KLASSE             VARCHAR2(200)
SGTN_SCHULE             VARCHAR2(200)
SGTN_TELEFON        VARCHAR2(120)
SGTN_KONTONUMMER        VARCHAR2(120)
```

KUN:

```
KUN_ID          NUMBER(22)
KUN_SPI_ID          NUMBER(22)
KUN_LAN_ID          NUMBER(22)
KUN_MED_KBEZ    VARCHAR2(40)
KUN_NAME1           VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_MKZ         VARCHAR2(80)
KUN_TS          DATE(7)
KUN_AKTIV           VARCHAR2(12)
KUN_KTOINH          VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_BLZ         VARCHAR2(40)
KUN_BANK            VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_KTONR           VARCHAR2(80)
KUN_ZAHLART         VARCHAR2(4)
KUN_NAME2           VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_VORNAME         VARCHAR2(160)
KUN_STRASSE         VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_PLZ         VARCHAR2(60)
KUN_ORT         VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_TEL1            VARCHAR2(120)
KUN_TEL2            VARCHAR2(120)
KUN_FAX         VARCHAR2(120)
KUN_E_MAIL          VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_PSEUDONYM   VARCHAR2(120)
KUN_PWD         VARCHAR2(60)
KUN_CUST_ID         VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_GESCHLECHT  VARCHAR2(4)
KUN_K_NAME          VARCHAR2(80)
KUN_K_NR            NUMBER(22)
KUN_K_VALID         VARCHAR2(40)
KUN_ZUSATZ_1    VARCHAR2(400)
KUN_ZUSATZ_DATUM    DATE(7)
KUN_COMMENT         VARCHAR2(4000)
KUN_EVT_SMS         VARCHAR2(80)
KUN_EVT_E_MAIL  VARCHAR2(240)
KUN_COMMENT2    VARCHAR2(4000)
KUN_AKTIV_BIS   DATE(7)
KUN_FLG_AGB         VARCHAR2(4)
KUN_TITEL           VARCHAR2(200)
```

Thank you in advance for clues.

Greetings

R. Bada

Comment: What if your run only the following query: SELECT *   FROM sgtn WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245?

Comment: Are there equal emails with type 'T' and type 'L'? SELECT *
   FROM sgtn
  WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
        and sgtn_typ = 'T' AND (sgtn_e_mail IN 
        (SELECT sgtn_e_mail
          FROM sgtn
           WHERE sgtn_spi_id = 245
   AND sgtn_typ = 'L')) - does this gives any results? If not then there are no overlapping emails with sgtn_typ = 'T' and 'L'

Comment: @renathy: yes i get results. I wrote it  already in my post.

Comment: You probably just don't understand the result.  In the query you don't seem to understand, you don't actually select the data you report is missing.  Add that to the SELECT list, including the primary keys of all tables found in the FROM clause.  That will show you exactly what the result contains.

Comment: Hmm, and I don't understand you neither. What should I add to select list? Please explain it to me more clear if possible... Thank you.

Comment: You have noted that there are people with 'L' and 'T', but you have not wrote that those people has the same email. Are there people with 'L' & 'T' but with different emails? You are querint people with 'L' first. It gives you PEOPLE1-L EMAIL1, PEOPLE2-L EMAIL2 etc. Then you try to find people with 'T' that are not in above already selected results.

Comment: As I already wrote in my post: "There are 'duplicates' in sgtn table(some people are entered with 'T' and 'L'). And apart from that the whole record is the same".

Comment: @user897237:When you're executing the second query ,select * from sgtn... are you getting  people with type L also?

Comment: @GauravSoni: thank you! I think I get my error, but I can  check it tomorrow.

Comment: In your original query, add the following item to the select list:  sgtn.sgtn_typ so that you can see that detail in the result.

Comment: If you still have questions, create a testcase in sqlfiddle.com and describe exactly what you don't like about the result.